# No idea why this code will not work 

Tags: php, mysql, sql

for some reason I get this:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/walterg/public_html/phptest.php on line 50

Warning: mysql_close(): 5 is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in /home/walterg/public_html/phptest.php on line 60
```

I'm just trying to do a simple sql query but i get errors

my code is :

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","walterg_kaden","nope");

    if (!$con)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("walterg_learning", $con);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ralf");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
     {
        echo $row['name'];
    }



    mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: Check the return values of `mysql_select_db` and `mysql_query` (if either of them is equal to FALSE, that's your problem!)

Comment: larry, your sql is failing. it's always essential for debugging reasons - like the one you're experiencing today - to have a way of printing out any errors along the way through each sql execution a a fail safe so that if anything should go wrong you can make sure to print the error there and then as the error occurs so that you can locate and fix the problem right away.

Comment: @Pavan as a matter of fact, silly die(mysql_error()) won't let you *locate* the erroneous line.

Comment: what im trying to explain is that we can then eliminate whether it was the database selection that failed or if it was anything else. Writing or die functions in your code after sql executions allow us to make sure that everything went smoothly and if not we can first make sure that it had  nothing to do with the sql operations.

Comment: @Pavan ...and also confuse a fair user with weird messages while letting a potential hacker into all the inners of your site. Some PHP consumers have no idea that they are not the only visitors of their site.

Comment: *sighs* I should really have said this at the beginning. Yep you're right. This method would ideally be used during development. When your application goes live, it would be advisable to remove all die messages so as to not display hideous confusing messages to a user. Something more friendly can be written instead or messages can be completely hidden in the background and appropriate action to be taken from the application's side to maintain the flow of the program.

Comment: @Pavan why not to write already clean and usable code which doesn't need to be rewritten?

Comment: Could do, although do realize that people follow different software development methodologies. Some like yourself for example may follow a cleanroom methodology and others an iterative process etc. 
Each to their own.

Comment: @Pavan this "iterative process" exists only in your imagination. In the real life nobody of these poor PHP consumers ever have an idea of changing anything they copied from some online tutorial.

Comment: @Your Common Sense *sighs* -_- troll :)

Answer (score 1):

2 simple rules for you to get it right

First. Always run your queries this way, at least until you adopt some more intelligent way to deal with queries:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ralf";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$sql);
```

Second. **Trust your eyes!**

If database told you "there is no database selected" - so, it is. Means you are selecting wrong database in the earlier statement. Check spelling, database existence and such.
That's easy. You don't need no special knowledge for this - just a common sense.

Answer (score 0):

larry, your sql is failing. it's always essential for debugging reasons - like the one you're experiencing today - to have a way of printing out any errors along the way through each sql execution a a fail safe so that if anything should go wrong you can make sure to print the error there and then as the error occurs so that you can locate and fix the problem right away

Your SQL query is failing. Use the mysql_error();. This will display the problem.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ralf") or trigger_error(mysql_error());
```

There are Five steps to PHP database connections to follow:

```
    // 1. Create a database connection
    //      (Use your own servername, username and password if they are different.)
    //      $connection allows us to keep refering to this connection after it is established
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","OtlPHP07"); 
    if (!$connection) {
        die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
    }

    // 2. Select a database to use 
    $db_select = mysql_select_db("widget_corp",$connection);
    if (!$db_select) {
        die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
    }

?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Databases</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    // 3. Perform database query
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subjects", $connection);
    if (!$result) {
        die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
    }

    // 4. Use returned data
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $row["menu_name"]." ".$row["position"]."<br />";
    }

    ?>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
    // 5. Close connection
    mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

Comment: Okay I've done this, it's saying no database selected. But I have selected one, I"ve also tried including $con into the mysql_query() statement, but nothing

Comment: check the updated answer. This was taken from a Lynda php with mysql course i took online.

Comment: oh. dunno who is that lynda but they apparently have no clue.

Comment: are you trolling? Please comment on matters that will help the current situation. If you feel you have a suggestion that can actually help larry solve his problem then please feel free to write an answer in the separate section below :P

Comment: actually I am sick, for seeing these ugly php codes again and again.

Comment: actually you are posting them. For example, what is the point in using mysql_error() with mysql_connect()? what is the point in echoing "Database connection failed" if the error message already contains the same text?

Comment: For a beginner, everything is ideally laid out so that they can understand what goes on behind the scenes. How sql represents/throws an error. At first beginners may not understand whats going on or what the messages returned mean whenever an error is returned hence the labels at the beginning. Its a learning process for beginners. When they understand the message and the underlying reason that caused it through experience labels would no longer be needed. at the beginning every little helps :)
Please avoid extended discussions in comments we can move this discussion to a chat room if you like

Comment: that's just an empty blab. I asked you certain question. Instead of certain answer you started a lecture on the obscure subject. And you accuse others for trolling.

Answer (score -1):

There must be two reasons.....
1. may be you have mistaken in assigning table naem while using select query or while assigning host,username,password,db
2. you must use this before while loop

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){ while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
     {
        echo $row['name'];
    } }
```

hope that solves your problem

Comment: You don't really need to test `mysql_num_rows` before `mysql_fetch_array`. The loop will never iterate if the number of rows is zero. Also, the function `mysql_num_rows` will still fail if its argument (`$result`) is `false`.

Comment: moreover, mysql_num_rows($result) will throw the same error. one have to check mysql_query return value, not mysql_num_rows() one

Answer (score -2):

This will tell you why your query is failing:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ralf") or die(mysql_error());
```